# Stripe test mode payments not resulting in balance

Tags: stripe-payments

I have set up checkout with Stripe, and successfully made purchases in test mode. The purchases show up, but my balance stays at 0.

I'd like to test paying out my balance to Connect accounts. Is balance not calculated in test mode, or does it take more than a few days to update? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When making a payment, the funds first go to the pending balance and then at a later date they move to the available balance.

If you need to get funds directly in your available balance in test mode, use one of the test cards listed in [this documentation page](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#available-balance).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! However, my current balance page shows both " Currently on the way to your bank account: $0.00" and 
"Funds on hold: $0.00". Should I expect to see pending balance there? How long is a balance pending for? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: If you successfully made a payment in test mode with the 4242 card, then funds should be added to your pending balance and then move to the available balance on a 7-day rolling basis (this timing can vary by country and account).

Comment: Test payment with 4242 was successful, but everything on the balance page says 0.00 ("Currently on the way to your bank account" and "Funds on hold"). Is Pending a separate category that's not displayed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the Stripe dashboard works, but you can use [the API to retrieve all balances](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_retrieve) (available, pending, etc.).